# I am not able to use "python manage.py dbshell" in visual studio code

Tags: python, django, sqlite, visual-studio-code

I have installed sq-lite program in my local machine & set environment variables also.
After that I am able to use "python manage.py dbshell" in command line but when using same command in visual code it showing error "CommandError: You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed or on your path."

I have attached screenshot also for reference.

In environment variables I have added "c:\sqlite" into path variable.

[dbshell_error_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWnI3.jpg)

Comment: install sqlite in your machine or else use `shell` instead of `dbshell`

Comment: I have already install sqlite in my machine so problem is that after that I am able to use dbshell in cmd but not in visual studio code.

Comment: is your virtualenv correctly set for the project? and also the sqlite is set in the environment path

Comment: yes I have added correctly in environment path also & virtualenv also working properly.I think need to set path in visual code also but not able to find any way for it.

Comment: have you restarted the machine after setting the environment path? as you are using windows you need to do that for the changes to take effect. do restart and check once again

Comment: Is your shell in VS Code cmd or PowerShell (the latter is the default so you may need to change it explicitly with the `Select Default Shell` command)?